# What is the best way to connect 6S lipo 22000mAh to step down converter?

Tags: batteries, power-electronics

Can I use below step down converters with the battery below? 
[image]

I will be using multiple step down converter to supply to other boards like (IntelUp_Squaredboard,motordriverboard).These are the links to my step down converter. 
[Step_Converter_1](http://sg.element14.com/mean-well/sd-15b-12/converter-dc-dc-15w-12v/dp/1299028) , [Step_Converter_2](http://sg.element14.com/mean-well/rsd-30g-5/dc-dc-converter-5v-6a/dp/2816113) . Let say if my board need 6A,should I buy exactly output 6A converter or 8A output converter?

Thank You All.

Comment: I always try to apply my rule-of-thumb of 150% rating, as you always get massive gulps during first power up. So I'd say, if you know your board uses 6A (absolute max), I'd find something that can do at least 9A. If I get the time later, I shall try and do a proper answer explaining how running at the limits always increases the risk of failure and makes everything less stable.

Comment: @Puffafish Thank you. I will use higher output for the step converter. How much current come out from this battery? Is it depend on my load?

Comment: yes it depends on the load, and also on the efficiency of the converter.